# Путь установки NodeJS

Tags: node.js

Установил вообщем NodeJS. Установилось в такую папку, что нашёл её только через панельку ISP Manager `/usr/ports/www/node/`

Как-то можно изменить путь?

Comment: Для чего его изменять?

Comment: @exec, я его увидел только через ISP MANAGER, где ужасный редактор http://cs317730.userapi.com/v317730173/73cb/g13Rf7m6z9U.jpg :( К тому же через filezilla эту папку не увидеть. Может я просто не понимаю что-то?

Comment: Я думаю удалить и установить в нужную папку. Я не разбирался с nodejs - ничего не знаю.

Comment: @exec, о боже. Час устанавливал, чтобы сейчас удалить :(

Comment: Я неделями мучаюсь с memcached, xcache, php 5.3 и прочим.

Comment: Это вопрос на форум [РутКод](http://admin.hashcode.ru).

Comment: Вы бы хоть сказали в какой ОС и как ставили.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете с официального сайта [node](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) скачать архив с бинарными файлами для вашей ОС и затем просто распаковать его по требуемому пути. Возможно, также придётся указать путь к каталогу `bin`  в переменной окружения `PATH`.

Comment: а как этот путь задать?

Comment: Вы бы сообщили бы свою ОС для начала. Для Linux добавьте в profile export PATH=$(PATH):/путь/до/каталога/с/node

Comment: ubuntu 14.хх....

Comment: Тогда я уже написал,  что сделать

Comment: http://forum.ubuntu.ru/index.php?topic=139129.0 здесь написано что в профиль нельзя, будет только на сессию... Это они ошибаются?

Comment: Там все правильно написано. Можно также внести изменения в /etc/profile, если хочется,  чтобы путь до node был доступен для всех пользователей. На мой взгляд,  лучше изменять переменную PATH в скрипте запуска приложения, использующего node.